# Calculate the time of operation between ON and OFF given Boolean (JavaScript, NodeRed)

Tags: javascript, node-red

I assumed, there are 2 button ON and OFF. When user click on ON, it will return a variable "button=True",
and when they click on OFF, it returns a variable "button=False". My questions is how to calculate the time between ON and OFF

```
const start = new Date();
let tt = msg.payload.d.running ; // this will return a Boolean value based on ON or OFF 

let l;
let h;

if(tt == true) {
   l = start.getMinutes(); 
}else {
   h = start.getMinutes(); 
  msg.result= h-l;
  return msg;    
}
```

Its is automatically ON when the user click on the website and the code will automatically run every time after ON and OFF are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getTime()` in order to get the Date objects, then subtract them and divide by 1000 (because it's originally in milliseconds).

I've added a snippet for example.

```js
let startTime;
let endTime;

function on() {
   setTime();
   //do stuff
}

function off() {
    setTime();
    //do stuff
}

function setTime(){
  if (!startTime){
    startTime = new Date();
  }
  else if (!endTime){
     endTime = new Date();
     logDiff();
  }
}

function logDiff(){
 console.log((endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="on()">On</button> // click me and then the other one
<button onclick="off()">Off</button>
```